# new 9-speed chain fails after 4 weeks and ~240 miles

Tags: chain, drivetrain

About 4 weeks ago I installed a new SRAM PC-971 chain on my Surly LHT. This morning I've noticed that one of the outer chain link plates started to pull away (to spread in a way that the pin is not engaged with the outer plate). My previous chain had failed in exactly the same way, but it was 50% worn according to a chain stretch checker. While riding this bike on a daily basis for over 6 years, I've never had this happen before. Does anyone have any ideas of why the chain is repeatedly failing in this fashion?

Drivetrain details:

- RD: Deore XT
- FD: Tiagra, triple;
- Cassette: SRAM 9-speed, 11-32t (reasonably worn, but not skipping yet);
- chainrings: original to the
  bike, reasonably worn, the teeth don't look terrible yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull away"? A photo would help.

Comment: I would check for a bent tooth somewhere in your drivetrain, under shifting a wayward tooth could bend the chain outer link plate away.

Comment: Did you close the chain when installing it by using a quick link or partially pressing a rivet out then pressing it back in?

Comment: I closed the chain using the supplied gold master link. By "pulling away" I meant that the chain link had spread so that one side of the outer plate was no longer engaged with its pin.

Comment: Rider_X, thanks! Your theory sounds very plausible and certainly fits the symptoms.

Comment: Did it fail at the masterlink?

Comment: If it's not due to improper assembly with a chain tool then one would suspect that something in the drive train is putting undue stress on the chain.  Could be a bent tooth, could be a maladjustment of the derailers, could be, eg, something amiss with the jockey wheels.

Comment: Occams Razer - could have been a faulty or poorly assembled chain out of the box?  Ask the bike shop if they've had a run of bad ones ?

Comment: Another theory : when the FD and RD create stress angle, and the chain does engage the correct tooth, at some right moment that strikes that particular link,  the torque will pull it open.  This happens because the chains is longer than the adequate, and Derailer are not suppose to compensate long chain. Please redo the calculation and shorten the chain by a few links.

Comment: The chain has failed at the link following the masterlink. I've assembled the chain exactly in the same fashion as multiple others in the last few years. I calculated the chain length by running it around big big sprockets (omitting  RD) and it was exactly the right length out of the box. I suspect that a bent tooth could be the culprit, but I won't have time to check it until the weekend.

Comment: *I calculated the chain length by running it around big big sprockets (omitting RD) and it was exactly the right length out of the box.*  That sounds very odd.  Most chains are supplied with about 8 inches of extra length, so that a single version of the chain can be used (after cutting) on many different bikes.  And if the chain is perfectly tight on the big/big combo then there is no slack to account for the need of the chain to "climb over" the cog during shifting.  You need to include a couple of extra links.

Comment: I swapped out the chainrings and have been riding for a few weeks without any problems. Since the chainrings were the only parts of the drivetrain that I replaced, I think they were to blame.

Comment: @user26323 Do you have pics of the old rings?

Comment: There is always sabotage. Where do you keep the bike when you're not riding it?

Comment: @DanielRHicks  I also recently put a SRAM chain on a bike, perhaps exactly the same one, on a bike, and found it was just about the right length already: not a lot to spare). 48-38-28 triple, 12-23 cassette, Sh. Acera derailleur (long cage, 13T cogs). Don't know the chainstay length. I should count the links; maybe it was short?

Answer (score 1):

You might not be installing the pin correctly. It sounds as if you did not reach the seating point or past it. Here is an article on Shimano chain installation (See drawings). http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-installation-derailleur-bikes

Comment: Because Park like the shuffle their website regularly, invalidating all links, it's much better to summarise the article and provide the title rather than just a link. We have a lot of broken links to Park from here, unfortunately.

Comment: What pin? This SRAM PC-971 chain almost certainly came with a master link. Unless he didn't know what that is and didn't use it ...

Comment: Comment from May 31 from OP under question: *I closed the chain using the supplied gold master link.*

Comment: Archived link to link in answer https://web.archive.org/web/20200925131354/https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-replacement-derailleur-bikes